# Netsuite SuiteCloud IDE How to setup administrator user to not have two-factor authentication

Tags: netsuite, suitecloud

I would like to use the NetSuite SuiteCloud IDE (Eclipse plugin), but I am also an Administrator. If you're an Administrator NetSuite requires you to have two factor authentication enabled, but if you want to use the SuiteCloud IDE you can't have two factor authentication enabled. How does one get out of this Catch-22?

I'm new to NetSuite so I don't know much about setting up roles. Do I just add another role with full permissions (or what permissions are needed?)? How would the SuiteCloud IDE know to use that role? Or do I have to create myself as an employee twice with different emails (this would be bad since we don't have many users)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Administrator role with 2FA *can* be used with Eclipse IDE.

In your NS account as administrator, create a new integration:

Setup > Integration > Manage Integrations > New

Name your integration SuiteCloude IDE *or something like that*

Check the Token-Based authentication box.

Then from your Administrator dashboard, create a new access token.

Then in Eclipse, go to Manage accounts:

Netsuite menu > Manage Accounts

Select the account with the administrator role, and manage authentication.

Select the Administrator Role, and SAVE TOKEN.

Here you can enter the Token ID and Token Secret created in your NetSuite account.

Then you should be good to go in Eclipse. Make sure you set the Eclipse project to now use the Admin role.

Answer (score 4):

NetSuite has enabled and made mandatory 2FA for Administrators, so in order to use SuiteCloud Plugin, you will have to use role other than Administrator.

> do I have to create myself as an employee twice with different emails
>   No, you can assign multiple roles to single user and then select that role in SuiteCloud Plugin.

I haven't used SuiteCloud plugin for a long time, but I think NetSuite has added feature to login using TBA.(not 100% sure though)

> How would the SuiteCloud IDE know to use that role?
>   When you provide your creds in Eclipse, it specifies all the accounts and roles that are assigned to the current user, so you can select any role except administrator which has access to file cabinet.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to enable two-factor authentication for your administrator role, or, create another role for development and use that. (Preferred.) If you look in the [NetSuite help](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_1519167260.html) there is a topic on setting up TBA with Eclipse.

Comment: Seconding the custom role as the preferred approach. Also note that in 2019.1, a new standard Role "SDF Developer" will exist. It will be the best practice to leverage this Role with TBA for all your SDF/IDE needs.

Comment: Starting 2019.1 (new 2018.2 accounts) : you can't use Administrator role for SDF because the 2FA became required and not possible to remove.

Comment: See my answer below. 2FA can be used with Administrator role in Eclipse IDE